# Deleting multiple materials from multiple objects?

Tags: materials

I imported a model from another app, since I didn't want to have to create it from scratch (not sure that was a good idea). The model was essentially a collection of multiple primitives, color coded by categories, organized by their x, y, z coordinates. Maybe a dozen shader categories, over 300 primitives.

It imported into Blender as a single object. I can (and have, mostly) manually select the primitives while in edit mode and separate the primitives back into separate objects, and they even retain (sort of) the essence of the original shading. However, each object has over 300 materials slots (the number of primitives in the original model), not just a dozen or so (the number of shaders in the original model). Only one of the slots is active for any particular object.

I can remove the unused materials from each individual object with the "Remove Unused Slots" command. However, I'm pretty sure that when I tried that while multiple objects were selected, it only cleaned up the slots for one of them. I know that, once I remove the unused slots, I can select multiple objects and get them to use the same material using CNTL L (link).

Is there an easy way to clean up the unused slots for multiple objects first?

Comment: Does File > Clean Up > Unused Data Blocks do the job in this case?

Comment: No, it does not. I should have mentioned that. Presumably because the materials are not unused. Before I started editing, each primitive was assigned an individual material, like "red.001" and "red.002." Both identical shades of red, but two materials.

Comment: I think you've got a lot of work on your hands in that case unless someone can come up with some Python code to do it! :^(